# How to groupby and count values in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe *procs*, where each month several **id**s took place, and also each **id** took place several times:

`procs.groupby(['month', 'id']).size()`

```
month               id                   
2015-02             UA-2015-02-06-000018-L1       5
                    UA-2015-02-09-000009-L1      10
                    UA-2015-02-10-000001-L1       5
                    UA-2015-02-10-000010-L1       3
                    UA-2015-02-16-000002-L1       6
                    UA-2015-02-26-000005-L1       6

2015-03             UA-2015-03-05-000001-L1       2
                    UA-2015-03-05-000003-L1       2
                    UA-2015-03-05-000004-L1       4
                    UA-2015-03-06-000009-L1       1
                    UA-2015-03-06-000010-L1       6
                              ...
```

I want to count number of **id** in each month. I have tried the variant below, but I get total number of rows in each month, not number of **id**'s:

`procs.groupby(['month'])['id'].count()`

```
month
2015-02       35
2015-03      209
2015-04      442
2015-05      497
2015-06      933
           ...
```

I need to get this:

```
month       number_id 
2015-02     6
           ...
```

Thanx for any help!

Comment: Strange, I have desired output when I test Your code. Please enclose input dataframe as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
procs.groupby(['month', 'id']).size().groupby(['month']).count()
```

Comment: Not sure how original `procs` looks like. Removed `id` maybe @Victor will check,

Comment: As @Ömrüm Çetin said, i need group of groups. Thank you guys. Also this variant `procs.groupby(['month', 'id']).size().groupby('month').count()` works

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from below comments you want group of groups :

```py
procs.groupby(['month','id'])['month'].count().groupby(['month']).count()
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `procs.groupby(['month', 'id'])['id'].count() `, but I get the same as `procs.groupby(['month', 'id']).size() `

Comment: So you want group of groups?

Comment: Yes this works fine, consider to upvote also @Ömrüm Çetin answer.

Comment: Upvoted, comments here helped me to fix my original answer.